# Air Install Badge Error

Tags: air

I have successfully created an AIR application using xhtml, css and javascript. The app installs properly on my local computer, but after creating the install badge using [BadgeBuilder](http://knomedia.com/air/badgeBuilder/) I get the dreaded Error# 2032.

I have Googled this to death but I have not been able to solve the problem. This is the final step on the project and I would really appreciate some help to resolve it.

I have now tried it using Grant Skinner's [Badger](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/09/beware_the_air.html) as well.

Still no joy. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was due to lack of support for .air MIME type on the host server. I found this great [post](http://www.davidtucker.net/2008/01/08/update-your-air-mime-type/) by David Tucker that gave me the information I needed. It would have been solved by a simple .htaccess file but this turned out to be an IIS server, which required that the MIME type be added to the HTTP headers in the server set up.